# Spring Controllers

Tags: spring-mvc, controller

Подскажите где можно почитать про то что происходит "под капотом" у подобных методов

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAll(Model model){
    return "words/view";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getAll(){
    return new ModelAndView();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public Map<String,Object> getAll(Model model){
    return new HashMap<String, Object>;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public ... getAll(...){
    return ...;
}
```

Я имею ввиду, что эти методы и принимают почти все, что хотят, и возвращают. Я понимаю что в самом спринге и почитать, но чего то я там не смог найти развернутый ответ на свой вопрос, возможно плохо хотел.

Comment: Если одним словом, то смотрите как работает `Spring IoC контейнер`, все методы выполняются внутри него (он же Dependency Injection (DI)), ну и полезным будет видео [spring-потрошитель](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BmBr5diz8WA)

Comment: Я имел ввиду не механизм Springа обработки аннотаций а как раз логику!